# Type 'Item' has no member 'init'

Tags: swift, generics

I have a little example where the line

```
items.append(Item(value: "A", id: index))
```

fails with:

> Type 'Item' has no member 'init'

and I don't understand the problem. Can you help?

```swift
struct Model<Item> where Item: Equatable {
    
    var items = Array<Item>()
    
    init(){
        items.append(Item(value: "A", id: index))
    } 
}

struct Item: Identifiable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    var value: any Equatable
    var id: Int
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do with this code. Why is `Model` generic? Why is its type parameter the same name as the struct `Item`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because the generic type `Item` has nothing to do with the struct `Item` and the compiler treats `Item` as generic type which doesn't have an initializer.

As you append the concrete type `Item` in the `init` method the generic type is pointless.

```
struct Model {
    var items = Array<Item>()
    
    init(){
        items.append(Item(value: "A", id: 1))
    }
}
```

which is practically the same as

```
struct Model {
    var items = [Item(value: "A", id: 1)]
}
```

To clarify the issue this is a generic method with a different type name

```
struct Model<M : Equatable> {
    var items = Array<M>()
    
    init(){
        items.append(Item(value: "A", id: 1))
    }
}
```

Of course this throws the compiler error

> Cannot convert value of type 'Item' to expected argument type 'M'

You can cast the type

```
items.append(Item(value: "A", id: 1) as! M)
```

but this makes the generic type pointless – as mentioned – because now `M` is equal to static `Item` and if you try to specify another type

```
let model = Model<String>()
```

you'll get a runtime error

> Could not cast value of type '__lldb_expr_1.Item' (0x104dc0118) to 'Swift.String' (0x1f7c94ab8).

which causes a crash.